# How to write form for multiple children of object in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Say I have these classes

```
class Company
  has_many :workers
end

class Worker
  belongs_to :company
end
```

I want a page where the company *and each worker* can be modified. My attempt was something like this:

```
= form_for @company do |f|
  = f.text_input :name
  -# etc..
  - @company.workers.each do |worker|
    = f.fields_for worker do |fw|
      = f.text_input :name
      = f.text_input :title
```

However, the fields for the worker have names  like `company[worker][title]` which doesn't include an identifier for the worker, so all the `title` fields for each worker have the same name.

What is the proper way to create a form for multiple objects belonging to a single object?

Comment: [`fields_for`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @max pointed out, you want to use `fields_for`. Specifically, you want to use the [one-to-many implementation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for-label-One-to-many).

This means your model will need to accept nested attributes

```
class Company
  has_many :workers
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :workers
end
```

And your form will be nested with a `fields_for` block, which you have but you are using the wrong block argument. Instead of `f` you want to use `fw`

```
= form_for @company do |f|
  = f.text_input :name
  -# etc..
  - @company.workers.each do |worker|
    = f.fields_for :workers, worker do |fw|
      = fw.text_input :name
      = fw.text_input :title
```

Comment: Thanks! The second mistake (`f` instead of `fw`) was just a goof on my example, now I don't know whether or not to edit the question.

Comment: I would leave it, it is two answers in one this way.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your code more succinct, using the [following](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for) (One-to-Many):

```
= form_for @company do |f|
  = f.text_input :name
  -# etc..
    = f.fields_for :workers, @company.workers do |fw|
      = fw.text_input :name
      = fw.text_input :title
```